# when picker view selected keyboard still visible

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uipickerview

i have a text field and picker view.when i select the text field picker view is appearing and if i select row in picker still my textfield is editable. i want to set textfield only in drop down list.and one more problem my key board is visible when i select the textfield

```
   - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


       [txtstate resignFirstResponder];//this is to hide key board
        txtstate.inputView=pickerView;


    ViewForValuePicker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(43,337, 212, 160)];
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(43, 0, 212, 30)];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneBtnPressToGetValue)];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:btn]];

    [ViewForValuePicker addSubview:toolBar];
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init] ;
    pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(43, 30, 212, 140);
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource= self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
         [ViewForValuePicker addSubview:pickerView];
    errstate.hidden=YES;
    [testScroll addSubview:ViewForValuePicker];
    [pickerView setHidden:NO];

   }


     - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
      forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
     UILabel *retval = (id)view;
         if (!retval) {
          retval= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,
             [pickerView    rowSizeForComponent:component].width,
                     [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)] ;
   }
   retval.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"Code"];
    retval.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12];


  return retval;
 }


     - (void)doneBtnPressToGetValue{

      [pickerView resignFirstResponder];

    [pickerView removeFromSuperview];
       txtcity.text=nil;
    autocompleteTableView.hidden=YES;
     [ ViewForValuePicker removeFromSuperview];


 }

  -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

     return 1;
    }

 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
  { 
   txtLId.text=[[arr objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"LId"]; 

    txtstate.text= [[arr objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"Code"];
   //txtstate.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

 } 

 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component; 
 { 
return [arr count]; 
 } 

  - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component; 
 { 

   return [[arr objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"Code"]; 
 }
```

Comment: Why are you assigning the pickerview to input only after you begin editing? That's most likely your issue.

Comment: actually i want the picker view programatically. when is select the text field then only it should appear.thats why iam assign there.is there any way to assign

Comment: actually i have an at right in text field like dropdown image.if i tapped then only it shuold appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello try and update following code with your code or check full code at http://pastie.org/6569798 :-

First define

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
```

in header file(.h).

```
- (void)createActionSheet {
    if (actionSheet == nil)
    {
        actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

        UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
        [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

        NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
        [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
        [flexSpace release];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneBtnPressToGetValue)];
        [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
        [doneBtn release];

        [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
        [barItems release];

        [actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolbar];
        [pickerToolbar release];

        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
        [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];
    }
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
     return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if(textField==txtstate)
    {
        pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init] ;
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 420);
        pickerView.delegate = self;
        pickerView.dataSource= self;
        pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        [pickerView setHidden:NO];

        [self createActionSheet];
        [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}


- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *retval = (id)view;
    if (!retval) {
        retval= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                          [pickerView    rowSizeForComponent:component].width,
                                                          [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)] ;
    }
    retval.text = [arr objectAtIndex:row];
    retval.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12];


    return retval;
}


- (void)doneBtnPressToGetValue
{
    [txtstate resignFirstResponder];

    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [actionSheet release];
    actionSheet = nil;
}
```

Comment: '+[UIActionSheet addSubview:]: unrecognized selector sent to class iam gtting error like this

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla I have edited answer by providing link for full code. Check link :- http://pastie.org/6569798

Comment: may be a simple question when action sheet will be called

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla : When you will call - (void)createActionSheet method it will create actionsheet and add it in view by [actionSheet showInView:self.view]; . Have you got above code working?

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- Also please do upvote and accept answer if you found solution from my answer.

Comment: iam facing some problem while adjusting frames

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- set your pickerview's frame like pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 420);

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- Can you tell me for size of toolbar?

Comment: UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 30)];

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- You can make arrangement by setting frame as you want.

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- Please remove [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

Comment: [actionsheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,212, 464)];

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- You can not change width of actionsheet.

Comment: but can i remove action sheet it hides my other textfields

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- when actionsheet will present you can do nothing on the screen, but you have to hide then you can interact with view.

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- If you don't want to use actionsheet then you can use custom view.

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- let me know what you think about that?

Comment: can i adjust action sheet frame

Comment: i hided the action sheet but iam not able to interact with view

Comment: give me idea about custom view

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- Have you implemented - (void)doneBtnPressToGetValue
{
    [txtstate resignFirstResponder];

    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [actionSheet release];
    actionSheet = nil;
}

Comment: even my tabbar items also not responding

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- Ok wait

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- ohh you have used tabbar?

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- use [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar]; instead of [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- then tell me what happen?

Comment: k now iam able to inter act with view but iam able to change the textfields value means if it is "states" converted to "stat"

Comment: got my point keybord is visible after donebtn action thats my need keyboard should be unvisible

Comment: - (void)doneBtnPressToGetValue{

    [txtstate resignFirstResponder];
    [actionsheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [actionsheet release];
    actionsheet=nil;}

Comment: iam not able to inter act with remaining textfields

Comment: what is first responder for txtstate

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- what happen if you click on remaining textfieldS?

Comment: iam not able to click my control is still at the end of textfield and  keyboard is visible

Comment: how toa attach pastie here

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- just copy whole code and then paste there, not to attach.

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla then give me link.

Comment: if i use txtstate.inputview=pickerview in didload it is showing pickerview at the bottom in place of key board.otherwise it is showing keyboard. i don't want keyboard

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla i have updated answer check it. Look at -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField and - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField method.

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- Also please remove txtstate.inputView=pickerView;

Comment: can i use txtstate.inputview= actionsheet

Comment: and one more thing i can say iam not able to add the data and able to delte data only

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- On click of txtstate textfield actionsheet is presented or not? what happen after pressing done button?

Comment: after pressing done button action sheet is disappeared and keyboard is visible and control is at the end of textfield

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- which method?

Comment: 6605638pastie.org plz see the link

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- Just create new project for demo and try to implement code from link :- http://pastie.org/6605748

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- Hmmm then please compare it with your code and find where is your problem.

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- If you find solution then please do upvote and accept answer as i have spend more time on this question with you to solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: k iam not getting where is the problem

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla :- Another solution is to use UIView instead of UIActionSheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your `textfield.inputview` in viewDidLoad itself with `pickerView`.

In `textFieldDidBeginEditing` - no more code required.

Also use your `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods as it is.

Comment: shall i create picker view in view didload only

Comment: but my picker should appear if i edit textfield what shall i do

Comment: It will appear that time only. You are just telling your compiler that for this text field dont use default keyboard, but use datepicker as an input view. Whereas in your case, when you are selecting textfield, compiler is not aware about custom input view, so its displaying default keyboard first. Then textfield delegate shown up and your picker view gets displayed. But that is wrong way to achieve this.

Comment: are u got mypoint. if i click image then only my pickerview should appear

Comment: i have one more problem.even i select row from the drop down it is editing that is if it is "state"iam able to convert into "stat"so its editable. so plz respod to me

Comment: UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 30)];

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have just the pickerview show up when you select the text field, take all of the code you have right now in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and move it into `viewDidLoad`. If you initialize `txtstate.inputView=pickerView;` before hand it will replace the keyboard as the main input.

Comment: Correct. Everything should be done by your viewDidLoad and corresponding delegate methods.

Comment: k i will try but my doubt is after view finish loading if i select textfield then only picker view should appear otherwise no.

Comment: with out selecting textfield only picker view is appearing.

Comment: Get rid of [pickerView setHidden:NO]; otherwise it will always appear.

Comment: it is replaced in place of keyboard. but i want exactly below the textfield

Comment: Then you should be adding the pickerview as a subview to the controller rather than a replacement for your textfield.

Comment: i added the picker view as a subview only

Comment: my issue is resolved but iam not able to edit the remaining textfields which are in my view.

Comment: [txtstate setFrame:CGRectMake(88, 306,212, 31)];

Comment: a light screen and tool bar is visible after selecting a row from picker